# Photoshop-How to add the layer arrow thing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

So I got PS a few days ago, and I've been working around a bit.

I was wondering what it was when someone snaps a layer to another one and it has like an arrow down on to the layer, and it colors any objects in the layer, how do I do it.

Sorry if it's already answered, I didn't really know what to search as I don't know the name of it.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/clipping-masks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a clipping mask.

1. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and move your mouse over the line that separates the two layers.
2. When the cursor changes to this [image], click it.

[image]

Note: You can also select a layer and in the main menu do *Layer > Create Clipping Mask*, or alternatively you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that it's located in menu `Layer > Create Clipping Mask`

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - done!